# How to create a 2D image by rotating 1D vector of numbers around its center element?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation

I have 1D vector of numbers which represents a center cut of a circular symmetric object. The vector itself is symmetric around its center element. I want to create in MATLAB a 2D image of the original object by rotating the 1D vector around its center element.

I tried the following code (with a dummy original vector of numbers) , but the center cut I get from the generated 2D image does not match the original 1D vector, as can be seen if you run the code. 
I'll appreciate any help !!!

```
close all; clc    

my1D_vector=[ zeros(1,20) ones(1,15) zeros(1,20)]; % original vector

len=length(my1D_vector);    
img=zeros(len, len);
thetaVec=0:0.1:179.9; % angles through which to rotate the original vector  
numRotations=length(thetaVec);

% the coordinates of the original vector and the generated 2D image:
x=(1:len)-(floor(len/2)+1);  
y=x;

[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

for ind_rotations=1:numRotations
    theta=pi/180*thetaVec(ind_rotations);
    t_theta=X.*cos(theta)+Y.*sin(theta);        
    cutContrib=interp1(x , my1D_vector , t_theta(:),'linear');
    img=img+reshape(cutContrib,len,len);
end
img=img/numRotations;

figure('name','original vector');plot(x,my1D_vector,'b.-')
figure('name','generated 2D image');  imagesc(x,y,img); colormap(gray) ; 

figure('name','comparison between the original vector and a center cut from the generated 2D image');
plot(x,my1D_vector,'b.-')
hold on
plot(x,img(find(x==0),:),'m.-')
legend('original 1D vector','a center cut from the generated 2D image')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What problem exactly do you find in your output figure? (I assume it's figure 2)

Comment: Please add comments or better yet, an explanation of your method

Comment: If you look at the comparison in Figure 3 between the original 1D vector  (blue) and a cut taken from the generated 2D image (magenta) you can see obvious differences.

Comment: I tried to rotate the original cut through various angles, and generate the 2D image by adding the results of the rotations. The interp1 is used in order to  convert the results of the rotations, which match a polar system, to the rectangular grid of the img matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't follow your code but how about this:

```
V = [ zeros(1,20) ones(1,15) zeros(1,20)]; % Any symmetrical vector
n = floor(numel(V)/2); 

r = [n:-1:0, 1:n]; % A vector of distance (measured in pixels) from the center of vector V to each element of V

% Now find the distance of each element of a square 2D matrix from it's centre. @(x,y)(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)) is just the Euclidean distance function. 
ri = bsxfun(@(x,y)(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)),r,r');

% Now use those distance matrices to interpole V
img = interp1(r(1:n+1),V(1:n+1),ri);

% The corners will contain NaN because they are further than any point we had data for so we get rid of the NaNs
img(isnan(img)) = 0; % or instead of zero, whatever you want your background colour to be
```

So instead of interpolating on the angle, I interpolate on the radius. So `r` represents a vector of the distance from the centre of each of the elements of `V`, in 1D. `ri` then represents the distance from the centre in 2D and these are the values we want to interpolate to. I then only use half of `r` and `V` because they are symmetrical.

You might want to set all the `NaN`s to `0` afterwards because you can't interpolate the corners because their radius is larger than the radius of your furthest point in `V`.

Using your plotting code I get

[image]

and

[image]

The blue and magenta curves overlap exactly.

---

## Explanation

Imagine that your vector, `V`, was only a `1`-by-`5` vector. Then this diagram shows what `r` and `ri` would be:

[image]

I didn't mark it on the diagram but `r'` would be the middle column. Now from the code we have

```
ri = bsxfun(@(x,y)(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)),r,r');
```

and according to the diagram `r = [2,1,0,1,2]` so now for each pixel we have the euclidean distance from the centre so pixel (1,1) is going to be `sqrt(r(1).^2+r(1).^2)` which is `sqrt(2.^2+2.^2)` which is `sqrt(8)` as shown in the diagram.

Also you will notice that I have "greyed" out the corners pixels. These pixels are further from the centre than any point we have data for because the maximum radius (distance from the centre) of our data is `2` but `sqrt(8) > sqrt(5) > 2` so you can't interpolate those data, you would have to extrapolate to get values for them. `interp1` returns `NaN` for these points.

Why does the interpolation work? Think of the position of each pixel as referring to the *centre* of the pixel. Now in this diagram, the red circle is what happens when you rotate the outer elements (i.e. `r==2`) and the green is rotating the elements 1 further in (i.e. `r==1`). You'll see that the pixel that gets the distance of `sqrt(2)` (blue arrow) lies between these two radii when we rotate them and so we have to interpolate that distance between those two pixels.

[image]

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand you code, and also I get some error running it (What's the bsxfun supposed to do? ). I also want to point out that the 1D vector I used in my program is only for the demonstration. My real original vector of numbers was gotten by an experiment and cannot be represented as an analytical function.

Comment: @OT you can replace `V` with any (symmetrical) vector, this should work fine on your experiment results. I edited the code about 14 minutes ago, perhaps you got errors on an earlier post which had some typos. Try it again, if you still get errors please post them.

Comment: @OT I've added a bit more of a detailed explanation, let me know if you still don't understand.