# How to create a 3D matrix in MATLAB by rotating 2D matrix around its center column or center row?

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D MATLAB matrix, which is symmetric with respect to its center column.  I want to rotate this matrix around its center column to produce a 3D matrix representing an object with a cylindrical symmetry.

The same thing I want to do with a different matrix, which is symmetric with respect to its center row. (This time I want to rotate it around its center row to produce the 3D matrix).

What I had in mind is to generalize to 3D the idea given in the link:

[How to create a 2D image by rotating 1D vector of numbers around its center element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810095/how-to-create-a-2d-image-by-rotating-1d-vector-of-numbers-around-its-center-elem)

But not knowing MATLAB well enough it is not a so straight forward task for me.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810095/how-to-create-a-2d-image-by-rotating-1d-vector-of-numbers-around-its-center-elem) to 3D:

```
% generate symetric matrix
A = zeros(11,31);
A(4:8,10:22) = repmat([1:7 6:-1:1],[5 1]);
% symmetric x axis
n = floor(size(A,2)/2);

% A vector of distance (measured in pixels) from the center of vector V to each element of V
[r,y] = meshgrid([n:-1:0, 1:n],1:size(A,1));

% Now find the distance of each element of a square 2D matrix from it's centre. @(x,y)(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)) is just the Euclidean distance function.
ri = sqrt( bsxfun( @(x,y)x.^2+y.^2,r,permute(r,[1 3 2]) ) );
yi = repmat(y,[1 1 size(A,2)]);

% Now use those distance matrices to interpole V
obj = interp2(r(:,1:n+1),y(:,1:n+1),A(:,1:n+1),ri,yi,'nearest');
obj(isnan(obj)) = 0;

% show
[xg,yg,zg] = meshgrid(1:size(obj,2),1:size(obj,1),1:size(obj,3));
scatter3(xg(:),yg(:),zg(:),10,obj(:)+1,'filled')
axis equal
```

**UPDATE** - if you don't want to use `interp2` you can do:

```
obj = interp1(r(1,1:n+1).',A(:,1:n+1).',ri(1,:,:),'nearest');
obj = permute(obj,[4,3,2,1]);
obj(isnan(obj)) = 0;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer !   I wanted to ask if there is a way of solving the problem with interp1 and without using interp2?

Comment: you can omit `y` and loop on the rows of `A` with `interp1` : `for row = 1:1:size(A,1);`  `obj(row,:,:) = interp1(r(row,1:n+1),A(row,1:n+1),ri(row,:,:),'nearest');`  `end`

Comment: Sorry for my nagging, but a loop will take too long for a large matrix. Is there another option? maybe using a reshape of the matrix or something of the sort?    Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you very much! One more thing: unfortunately, I haven't manage to translate the code for rotation around the center row for the other matrix, which has symmetry around the center row (and not center column). Can you please help me with that too?

Comment: it's straightforward to do that, just switch between dimensions in the relevant code lines.

Comment: Nevertheless, can you please write it explicitly.   (  I implemented it by transposing the 2D matrix, then used the 'rotate around center column' code, and then manually with a for loop constructed the desired 3D matrix by coping each slice along the vertical symmetry axis of the built matrix to a slice along the horizontal symmetry  axis of the desired matrix. But the for loop takes too much time. )